# Python: Processing POST multipart/form-data in REST Web Service

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I'm trying to process the data as well as the image file that's being POSTED to my REST web service.

```
files = {
    'image': ('youtried.jpg', (open('youtried.jpg', 'rb')), 'image/jpg', {'Expires': '0'}),
    'deojeff': 'Deojeff Value'
}

r = requests.post('http://localhost/service/images', headers={
    'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=******; chartset="utf-8"',
}, files=files)

print (r.text)
```

In my class that handles the post request. Basically it's just returning what's being posted. Which is good, at the moment.

```
def on_post(self, req, resp):
    """Creates an image."""
    x = req.stream.read()

    resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
    resp.body = x
```

But good isn't enough, I want to read the value, or do something with this response:

```
    --0de1791a1a3c4c78b3d1f3db9b0f6832
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="deojeff"; filename="deojeff"

Deojeff Value
--0de1791a1a3c4c78b3d1f3db9b0f6832
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="youtried.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg
Expires: 0

����^YiExif^@^@MM^@*^@^@^@^H^@^F^A^R^@^C^@^@^@^A^@^A^@^@^A^Z^@^E^@^@^@^A^@^@^@V^AESC^@^E^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^^A(^@^C^@^@^@^A^@^B^@^@^B^S^@^C^@^@^@^A^@^A^@^@�
i^@^D^@^@^@^A^@^@^@f^@^@^@�^@^@^@H^@^@^@^A^@^@^@H^@^@^@^A^@^G�^@^@^G^@^@^@^D0221�^A^@^G^@^@^@^D^A^B^C^@�^@^@^G^@^@^@^D0100�^A^@^C^@^@^@^A^@^A^@^@�^B^@
^D^@^@^@^A^@^@^A,�^C^@^D^@^@^@^A^@^@^A^]�^F^@^C^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^F^A^C^@^C^@^@^@^A^@^F^@^@^A^Z^@^E^@^@^@^A^@^@^A^N^AESC^@^E^@^@^@^A^@^@^A^V^A(
--0de1791a1a3c4c78b3d1f3db9b0f6832--
```

Basically what I need is to post/process two things:
1) The name
2) The image binary